# PHP setcookie is never setting

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to make a cookie. It doesn't make it.

This codes was working, but it doesn't work in recent system. login_check.html is the below.

```
<?
include "../_cfg/siteCfg.php"; //Site common values
include "$SITE_PATH/_class/dbms.php"; //mysql_class
include "$SITE_PATH/_class/Function.php";

$my_func = new PublicFunction();
$db = new mydb();   //DB Access

if ( $HTTP_POST_VARS[id] && $HTTP_POST_VARS[passwd] ) {
    $sql = "select uid, passwd, m_id, name, level from member_list where m_id = '$HTTP_POST_VARS[id]'";
    $result = $db->select($sql);

    if ( !$result ) {
        $my_func->virtual_function( "login_error ('ID_ERR')" );
    }
    else if ( $HTTP_POST_VARS[passwd] != $result[0][1] ) {
        $my_func->virtual_function( "login_error ('PW_ERR')" );
    }
    else if ( $result && ( $HTTP_POST_VARS[passwd] == $result[0][1] )) {
        $m_id = $result[0][m_id];
        $uid = $result[0][uid];
        $name = $result[0][name];
        $level = $result[0][level];

        setcookie("c_m_id",$m_id,0,'/');
        setcookie("c_uid",$uid,0,'/');
        setcookie("c_name",$name,0,'/');
        setcookie("c_level",$level,0,'/');

        $my_func->virtual_function("alert($_COOKIE[c_level])");  // This is for a log

    $my_func->virtual_function( "loginOk()" );
    }
} else {
    $my_func->virtual_function("alert('Bad Access!!!')");
}
```

?>

When I make a alert to check COOKIE Values, It's null.

And I used var_dump(isset($_COOKIE[c_uid]));, ant then it returns  **bool(false)**  .

Plus I changed header **@header('P3P: CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC OTC"');** to **header('P3P: CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"');** .

This also not worked.

This code is called by the below. The above code is login.html

```
<?
    require_once "$DOCUMENT_ROOT/_cfg/siteCfg.php"; //site value
    require_once "$SITE_PATH/_class/htmlHead.php";

    $title = "Login"; //title value
    $htmlTPL = new htmlTPL($title); //HEAD Instance creation
?>
<title></title>
<link href="<?=$SITE_HOME?>/_styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$SITE_HOME?>/_js/common.js"></script>
<script>
//<!--
    function login_check(){
        var fm = document.login_form;

        fm.target = "vr_url";
        fm.action = "./login_check.html";
        fm.submit();
    }
    function login_error ( num ) {
        fm = document.login_form;
        if ( num == "ID_ERR" ) {
            alert ( "Not registered user.");
            fm.passwd.value = "";
            fm.id.focus();
            fm.id.select();
        } else if ( num == "PW_ERR" ) {
            alert ( "Wrond Pasword." );
            fm.passwd.focus();
            fm.passwd.select();
        }
    }

    function loginOk(){
        opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    }
//-->
</script>
```

This is a part of siteCfg.php

```
<?
//@header("Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate");
//@header ("Pragma: no-cache");
@header('P3P: CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC OTC"');

//header('P3P: CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"'); 
//error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$SITE_PATH  = $DOCUMENT_ROOT;
$IMG_PATH = $SITE_PATH."/image";
$MANAGER_PATH = $SITE_PATH."/manager";


$SITE_HOME  = 'http://www.mysite.com';
$MANAGER_HOME = $SITE_HOME."/manager";
$IMAGE_HOME = $SITE_HOME."/image";
$ADMIN_HOME = $SITE_HOME."/manager_admin";

//Login Return URL
$PREURL = urlencode($SITE_HOME.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

//Values Setting

$_name = $_COOKIE[c_name];
$_mid = $_COOKIE[c_m_id];
$_uid = $_COOKIE[c_uid];
$_mlevel = $_COOKIE[c_level];

//var_dump(isset($_name));      

//FTP Setting
```

PHP Version 5.2.17 . Is therea anything I can check to solve this problem. Please, tell me.
I tested on IE 11, Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m , Firefox, Safari. not working at all

Comment: are you sure  `else if ( $result && ( $HTTP_POST_VARS[passwd] == $result[0][1] )) {` loop is being called ?

Comment: Have you checked that no content is being sent before `setcookie` is called? If anything is written to the output, the HTTP headers will be sent and it will be too late to set cookies. Very often, you will find that a file has been edited and the editor has put a Unicode byte-order mark at the start of the file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045550/php-session-id-changes-between-pages/2045630#2045630

Comment: I checked entring else if ( $result && ( $HTTP_POST_VARS[passwd] == $result[0][1] )) . by adding alert.

Comment: When this page is shown up, I couldn't find Message like **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ~ **, not using obstart(). I'm also checked echo, var_dump or other print method. I couldn't find it.

Comment: I also have been used **error_reporting(E_ALL);** I checked warnings like **Notice: Undefined index: c_name in ~**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a blankspace at the beginning of your script.
Cookies won't be set if you have HTTP body before it.

See:

```
 <?
^-----
include "../_cfg/siteCfg.php"; //Site common values
incl....
```

Also your coding style [can be much improved](http://www.phtml.org). Not using short-open-tags for example and putting single-quotes arround string index: `$varRS['id']`.

This won't work:

```
virtual_function("alert($_COOKIE[c_level])");
```

you need to properly concatenate variables and use quotes arround strings:

```
virtual_function("alert(" . $_COOKIE['c_level'] . ")");
```

If you don't see any error messages, make sure you have error reporting turned on.
http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/

Comment: That's my mistake during copy & Paste. Actually, the space you mentioned not existed in actual codes.

Comment: I rechecked it as you suggested. Alert shows up nothing. The code works when the value is integer. I tested it at the other code. Actually I have a question why it's not working for strings. Your way makes my question satisfied.

Comment: there is a difference for `$variable[test]` and `$variable['test']` in the first test is a constant, in the second its a string.
see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Just always escape variables and wrap strings in (single-)quotes then you are safe. For example use this: `include($SITE_PATH . "/_class/Function.php");`

Comment: I used expressions like variable['test']. But it doesn't work. This looks like not a solution for me. I checked at phpInfo(). But cookie values not registered.

Comment: Check 3 things using firebug or similiar: 1. Does the cookie get sent 2. Does the cookie get saved 3. Does the cookie get send back to the server. You check this with your browser, not with phpinfo

Comment: PHPinfo() can print Values of Cookies. Actually, this login process is working by calling **window.open**. When I checked cookie saving in other pages, It works. So, I guess this symptom is related to the situation which login check process is proceeding on popup by calling **window.open**. Is there anyong who knows this problem?

Comment: thats why u sould take a look at the headers with your browser, not with phpinfo

Comment: I checked it again by using Firebug. I found five warnings. like Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/hosting_users/www/member/login_check.html:1)              But this form as above, login_check.html if full php code and login.html calls login_check.html by function login_check(). I couldn'r find any blank or other things. Where could I check?

Comment: Finally I found one blank. I changed editor to test this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly what I said from beginning hehe glad you finally found the error =)

Answer (score 0):

You might try to convert $HTTP_POST_VARS to $_POST (since $HTTP_POST_VARS is deprecated and I'm not even sure it's still supported with PHP > 5, which might be very well your issue if it stopped working on a new system).

Comment: As commented above, I checked entering the third **else if** loop - setcookie section. So, using $HTTP_POST_VARS is not a main issue if not exsiting another reason.